# Abolish off-topic tags [etymology] and [resources]

Tags: discussion, tags, on-topic-off-topic

There are about 20 questions tagged [etymology](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology), and 8 questions tagged [resources](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources).  Both are clearly off-topic according to the [Help Center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Of the existing questions, they are either improperly tagged, or off-topic and unsalvageable.  All of them should either be retagged or deleted.

The existence of these tags gives the impression that such questions are allowable on ELL.  I propose that they be abolished and blacklisted.

Please indicate your agreement by upvoting the answers, or post a counterproposal as an answer.

Comment: Related question: [Why are there \[archaic\], \[early-modern-english\], and \[history\] tags?](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1182/5289)

Comment: It looks like the Community bot just bumped this related question also: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1107/9161

Comment: So, at what point would we decide that "yes, it should be deleted" or "no, let's keep it" and what's the next step? It looks like a suggestion was made to delete [tag:resources] a few months ago and nothing definitive ever came of it.

Comment: @ColleenV I was hoping to get more than four measly votes in favour. But if Meta participation is low, maybe that's all the consensus we're going to get. I'll ask the Stack Exchange staff to go ahead with the burnination of [tag:resources] and [tag:etymology].

Comment: I wonder if it would make sense in the future to post the opposing option as a question also, i.e. "I think we should keep the tag".  (Never mind - I just realized I can click on the number to see the totals)

Comment: I've made my case in the question. If you want to keep the tags, you should state why, and that requires posting an answer, not just a vote.

Comment: Yes, you're right - we're not designing a survey here :)

Comment: SE staff have recommended that we manually retag each question, since there are not that many of them.

Answer (score 7):

I agree that [etymology](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) should be abolished and blacklisted.  Existing answers with the tag should either be retagged as appropriate, or deleted.

Comment: Removing [tag:resources] seems more clear cut to me. I know [tag:etymology] is off-topic, but in some cases, a practical look at etymology might be helpful. If someone asks "this word looks a lot like a word in my native language. Is it related?" it is a question of etymology, but it would be helpful in understanding or remembering English words that have crossed over from other languages.

Comment: @ColleenV Perhaps you should post that as an answer, proposing deletion but not blacklisting.

Comment: I guess I'm not clear about the difference between deletion and blacklisting - I assumed it would mean no-one could propose the tag in the future. It makes sense to me that if we go through the trouble of deleting the tag, we wouldn't want it to crop up again in the future.

Comment: @ColleenV That is correct.

Comment: So, does [tag:etymology] add information that would be useful in searching the site for similar questions or answers, even though straight etymology questions are off-topic? I'm not sure it does, but with only 20 questions tagged that way, I'm not sure it does too much damage to be left alone if there isn't a clear consensus. I think if we decide to delete it, it should also be blacklisted so we don't have to have this conversation multiple times.

Comment: Most of the etymology questions are only incidentally about etymology, or aren't really about etymology at all. Half of them came recently from a single user, and the community has already expressed considerable distaste for them: after the first few they've been closed. I think the tag can disappear with no loss.

Comment: I suppose I'm "gaming" the system by upvoting *both* copies of the same answer, whilst asking the mods to merge the two. But it seems a no-brainer to me that neither of these tags are appropriate. Many questions thus tagged are *closed*, obviously. But I don't see we'll miss anything useful by removing inappropriate tags from questions which are otherwise acceptable. Tags disappear when they're not used, so a round of tag editing is called for here. Unless anyone seriously wants to post an answer supporting keeping the tags (which I for one would *downvote*).

Comment: I've started introducing a [tag:roots] tag (which also exists on EL&U) for questions about how to interpret a word based on its components, but that do not ask about the history of a word.

Comment: [A question asked today](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41099/do-kidnappers-only-kidnap-kids) is tagged `etymology`. I find the tag appropriate for the question and the question appropriate for ELL.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung That is a good ELL question. A [roots] tag could work. Or maybe we rename [roots] to [word-deconstruction] (and synonymize). Or we abolish the prohibition against etymology questions. Either way, something needs to be done. What do you think?

Comment: @200_success As far as what should be done? I’m not sure. It seems likely that most people using the tag will be in the process of asking an OT question, but not in every case. If there’s room in the tag description, maybe we could craft a warning or disclaimer.

Answer (score 5):

I agree that [resources](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) should be abolished and blacklisted.  Existing answers with the tag should either be retagged as appropriate, or deleted.

Comment: I've removed the resources tag from all questions which bore it.